# What conditions cause Devise to sign out?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

When I first migrated from Restful Authentication to Devise the Destroy methods caused Devise to sign out because of a missing CSRF token that was missing.  I remember reading that Devise signs out if it can't do something (like maybe access a method), but I am unsure what exactly causes it to sign out.
What are possibilities that could cause Devise to sign out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One condition that causes it to sign out is a **missing authenticity_token** as one of the input values of a form.  This happened to me because I created the form in Kompozer them copied and pasted it into Rails.  To declare the authenticity token in the form the best solution would probably be to use the form helper http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

This token must exist to prevent CSRF attacks.